# How do I find and replace a (.) at the beginning of a line in a txt file with regex to then delete it?

Tags: python

I have a program that logs the keys pressed and then writes them to a .txt file. Problem is that (there may be a better way) I have my code to start a new line '\n' every time that a (.) is pressed but the period goes into the next line instead of staying in the previous line. Basically, I don't want the .txt file to start every new line with a .(.)

In the code I don't have the regex implemented, I hope you'll help me with that and then to delete what the regex finds. Which will be a new line that's starting with a (period).

```
from unicurses import *
import os

def copy():
    stdscr = initscr()
    file = open("pressed_keys.txt", "a")  # open and append file
    true = True
    while true:
        key = getch()
        addstr(chr(key))
        if key == 46:  # (.) period
            file.write('.')
            file.write('\n')
            # file.  >> something to delete the previous key pressed
        elif key not in (27, 10):  # ESC key | ENTER
            addstr('ASCII code for %s is %s \n' % (chr(key), str(key)))  # prints the key code to the terminal window
            file.write(chr(key))  # writes the pressed key to the 'file'
        else:
            file.close()
            true = False
            endwin()


if os.path.isfile('./pressed_keys.txt'):
    #  comment the next line to not clear the file when the program runs
    open('pressed_keys.txt', 'w').close()
    copy()
else:
    file = open('pressed_keys.txt', 'w+')  # create a file if it does not exist
    copy()
```

Comment: Can't you just use `lstrip('.')` on each line?

Comment: Where and how would I implement this on the code?

Comment: @Austin, `lstrip` removes not only the first `.` (although maybe this is what OP wants).

Comment: Do I have this right?  You want to remove this character after it gets written to the file you're writing to because you don't understand how it is getting there in the first place?

Comment: @Steve When I run the program and type "read this.and this". I get "read this." then on the next line I get ".and this". Its on this second line that I get a (period) which I want to get rid of.

Comment: @dyukha, *"Basically, I don't want the .txt file to start every new line with a .(.)"* So I guess not only the first.

Comment: you get period in file because you use `if key == 46: ... if key != 27 | 10: ... ` but you should use `if ... elif....`

Comment: `key != 27 | 10` doesn't work as you expect. It works as `(key != 27) | 10`. You need `if key != 27 or key != 10:` or `if key not in (27, 10):`

Comment: @furas Thank you, this has removed the period at the beginning of a new line, but now I have a white space at the beginning of every line. How would I got about removing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said you have problem because it writes dot at the beginning of line.

Problem is because you use `if ... if ...` but you should `if ... elif ...` in

```
    if key == 46:  # (.) period
        file.write('.')
        file.write('\n')
        # file.  >> something to delete the previous key pressed
    if key != 27 | 10:  # ESC key | ENTER
        addstr('ASCII code for %s is %s \n' % (chr(key), str(key)))  # prints the key code to the terminal window
        file.write(chr(key))
```

First `if` compare dot with `46` and it writes `"\n"` in file but after next `if` compares `dot` with `!= 27` which is true so it write `dot` in new line.

You have to use `if ... elif ...` to stop it.

```
    if key == 46:  # (.) period
        file.write('.')
        file.write('\n')
        # file.  >> something to delete the previous key pressed
    elif key != 27 and key != 10:  # ESC key | ENTER
        addstr('ASCII code for %s is %s \n' % (chr(key), str(key)))  # prints the key code to the terminal window
        file.write(chr(key))
```

BTW: `key != 27 | 10` doesn't work as you expect you need `key != 27 and key != 10` or `key not in (27, 10)`

Comment: when writing (27, 10) is that basically saying (27 or 10) or (27 and 10)? Also I'm getting a white space after instead of period at the beginning of every line. It I were to be typing a couple sentences I would press SPACE after the (period) but since the program writes in a new line after the (period) is pressed. I don't need the whitespace to show even though im typing it.

Comment: it is tuple `(27, 10)` so it says nothing. But `key not in (27, 10)` works as `key != 27 and key != 10`. Without `not`  (`key in (27, 10)`) it will works like `key == 27 or key == 10` - so with `not` it is `and`, without `not` it is `or`

Comment: if you don't need space then you have to create `if` statement to skip it. if you don't need space after `period` they you have to remember previous `key` and check `if key == 32 and previous_key == 46: pass`

Comment: How would I remember the previous key? This is new to me, like the tuple. Im trying to make this key logger by gathering info and not from a step-by-step video.

Comment: how do you remeber current key ? you have variable `key` for this - ie. `previous_key`. Before you get new key `key = getch()` you have to save old key in this variable `previous_key = key`. It may also need some value for `key` at start so you may set `key = None` before `while True`

Comment: Thank you so much. This is now solved. You seem to know alot about python. Would you know how to make this program run and record every key pressed while being in like... Chrome, firefox, notepad? Like run the program and it'll record and save it to a file once the program stopped? My guess is to have it run as a terminal command but then if the terminal is closed how would the program keep on running? Do you have videos explaining things about python?

Comment: on Linux/Unix (and probably Mac) you can add `&` after command in terminal and it will run in background - probably it should run after closing terminal. But system may not send keys to programs which don't have window or they are hidden/minimalized. Some people use function in module PyQt to create keylogger. On Linux I use `AutoKey` to run some function when I press key combination in any program - and AutoKey is created in Python. I don't rember what module it uses but you can see it in its source code.

Comment: other module which can catch keys - [pynput](https://pythonhosted.org/pynput/keyboard.html). Also look for `keylogger in Python` in Google.

Comment: I've run the program and the terminal outputs " [3] 5529 ". If I press any key while on the terminal the program stops. I typed a few keys before stopping it but nothing save to the file. Any idea on to what this means? I'm running Kali Linux.